# Fill in elements of Pandas DataFrame element by element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame that needs to be re-represented. The original data frame has each row as a unique search term and the columns are all the resulting products. So each row is a different length.

I want to turn this into a rectangular dataframe (called rectangle in the code below) where the rows are still unique search terms, but the column headers are all the unique products. Each element will now be a 1 or 0 to represent whether that product is a result of that search term.

Here is what I have:

```
AshwiniInput = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../AshwiniInputData.csv')
AshwiniInput = AshwiniInput.set_index(keys='search_term_orig',drop = True,verify_integrity=True )    

#Get all unique products as a list
AllProducts = pd.unique(AshwiniInput.values.ravel())
AllProducts = [str(product) for product in (AllProducts)]

def MakeBoolDictOfSearchTermsAndProducts(Term, ProductsRelatedToTerm, AllProducts):
    """
    Use on each search term in AshwiniInput to get dict with 1 or 0 for each product
    """
    returnDict = {}
    for product in AllProducts:
        if product in ProductsRelatedToTerm:
            returnDict[product] = 1
        else:
            returnDict[product] = 0
    return Term, returnDict


rectangle = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape = (len(AshwiniInput.index),len(AllProducts))),
                          index = AshwiniInput.index,
                          columns = AllProducts)
```

How do I iterate over each row and column in `rectangle` to run my function `MakeBoolDictOfSearchTermsAndProducts()` on it and fill in the correct element with the result? Should I use apply? or map? or perhaps apply_map?

Comment: Are you trying to build a Term Data Matrix? If so, don't reinvent the wheel. Just use something like **CountVectorizer** from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).

Comment: The CountVectorizer is close, but my input file isn't set up to be read into it. Also CountVectorizer uses the set of all words as the vocabulary. I only want each element of the lists to be in the vocab (not broken up by word).

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand the problem without sample data. Isn't the CSV a rectangle already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, Pandas Dataframe is good if you want to iterate over rows and treat each row as a vector. I would suggest that you use 2-dimensional numpy array. Once you have the array, you can iterate over each row and columns very easily. Here is the sample code:

```
`for  index, value in ndenumerate( self.cells ):
    do_something( value )
    self.cells[index] = new_value`
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../AshwiniInputData.csv')
rectangle = df.groupby(['product','search term']).\
    size().unstack('search term').astype(bool)
```

Comment: Where would you get `'product'`? in the function definition for loop?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a column for 'product' and a column for 'search term' in your CSV file. See, without a sample of your input I'm left to guessing here.